# Does adding an object to a nested field reindex?

Tags: elasticsearch

With nested objects you have an array of objects:

```
comments: [
   {field1, field2, ..}
]
```

When you want to add a new object to the comments, does ElasticSearch reindex the whole document?

```
comments: [
   {field1, field2, ..},
   {newField1, newField2, ...}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two options

- either Updating a Whole Document (reindex it) https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/update-doc.html or
- perform partial update https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html

in above mention both options elasticsearch internally manages the same "retrieve-change-reindex" process